# Workbox Stale-while-revalidate strategy always returns response from network call instead of cache

Tags: service-worker, workbox, workbox-webpack-plugin

I am using [workbox-webpack-plugin](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-webpack-plugin), below is code in webpack config

```
new GenerateSW({
  runtimeCaching: [
    {
      urlPattern: new RegExp('^https://devapi\.mysite\.xyz/'),
      handler: 'staleWhileRevalidate',
      options: {
        cacheableResponse: {
            statuses: [200]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

Below is flow of stale while revalidate strategy as per [google doc](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/offline-cookbook/#stale-while-revalidate)

[image: Stale while revalidate flow - Google Doc]

I am calling API from cross domain, what I observed is each time response is given back to UI not from cache but from network call response.

I am expecting when same API is called 2nd time, I should get response from cache and then cache should be updated from response of network call.

Answer (score 1):

I think all the info in this "[Handle Third Party Requests](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/handle-third-party-requests)" guide should help.

In particular, make sure that your remote server is using CORS, or else you'll get back a `response` that has a status of `0`. You're explicitly configuring the `cacheableResponse` plugin to only cache responses with a status of `200`.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling upon this now, the correct snippet should be.
Workbox listens to `StaleWhileRevalidate` not `staleWhileRevalidate`.

```
new GenerateSW({
  runtimeCaching: [
    {
      urlPattern: new RegExp('^https://devapi\.mysite\.xyz/'),
      handler: 'StaleWhileRevalidate',
      options: {
        cacheableResponse: {
            statuses: [200]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
})
```